# How we load the jquery function only one time

Tags: javascript

I just want that my jQuery function run only one time. Currentyl i am using the country,state/cites drop down. So when user select any country it show the cities/state. But initial it show nothing, so i call it on document.ready. But the problem is that is show first country cities every time. So is there any solution for that. Or can you suggest any other country, cities drop down.

The Code for drop down is

```
function print_country(country_id){
// given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
var option_str = document.getElementById(country_id);
var x, i=0;
for(x in country_arr){
    option_str.options[i++] = new Option(country_arr[x],country_arr[x]);
}
}

function print_state(state_id, state_index){
var option_str = document.getElementById(state_id);
var x, i=0; state_index++;
var state_arr = s_a[state_index].split("|");
for(x in state_arr){
        option_str.options[i++] = new Option(state_arr[x],state_arr[x]);
}
}
```

You can also modify it so that on page load the cites of first country show by default. Thanks

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/ has a `once` function that takes a function and returns a function that memomizes the result. You can see the source here: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-66

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use jQuery now you have it

```
function print_country(country_id){
  // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
  var countrySel = $("#"+country_id);
  // create a "singleton" by returning if the state exists
  if (countrySel.size() > 1) return;
  $.each(country_arr,function() {
      countrySel.append('<option value="'+$(this)+'">'+$(this)+'</option>');
  });
  // call it with the second option (assuming "Please select")
  // change to ,0 for first option
  print_state("state", 1); 
}

function print_state(state_id, state_index){
  var stateSel = $("#"+state_id);
  var state_arr = s_a[state_index].split("|");
  $.each(state_arr,function() {
    stateSel.append('<option value="'+$(this)+'">'+$(this)+'</option>');
  });
}
```

Comment: Currentyl i am using this code `var state_id = jQuery('#statecheck').attr('id');
 print_state_checkbox(state_id, 0);`

By this when user can able to see the first country cities, But this  function show the country of first country every time.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by every time. Please post more code and your arrays

Comment: I am using this [example](http://bdhacker.wordpress.com/2009/11/21/adding-dropdown-country-state-list-dynamically-into-your-html-form-by-javascript/). If you see demo the first country is shown but its cites are not shown. i want cities of that country as well on first time load

Comment: You missed a "should" "The function should show the states of the first country when first loaded" - see update

Comment: i don't get you, where is that update i can't see it. can you provide me the link or code. I really thanks full for you

Comment: look at the line `print_state("state", 1);`